# Как протоколировать деятельность потоков в файл?

Tags: java

Учусь писать многопоточные приложения.
Нужно все, что делают потоки записывать в файл. Если я правильно понимаю нужно протоколировать всякие Sleep,Join,Start и так далее.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: AOP - посложнее, простой логгер - попроще

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы не знаете как писать в файл?

Comment: Наверно вопрос чуть не правильно сформулировал,больше интересует что я должен писать в файл,какую информацию?

Comment: @АндрейКузьмин точно знает только тот, кому вы должны.

Comment: Мне кажется протоколирование это звучит сложно и сбивает с толку, т.к. есть протоколы. Логирование, логи вот что проще и понятнее :)